# Can't see contents of shared folders in homegroup

Tags: windows, networking, homegroup

I can see other people in my homegroup and their folders, but when I click on those folders, I cannot see the contents.

When I click a folder, this message appears:

> Windows cannot access\PC2\Folder1
>   You don't have permission to access. Contact your network administrator to request access.

What can I do to solve that?

Comment: See this...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/homegroup...and this...http://www.guidingtech.com/3758/quickly-share-files-homegroup-widows-7/

Comment: If they are not all Windows 7 PC's also see this...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows